# Write in a XML file with JQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have an XML file and a PHP file in the same folder. The XML file has the following structure:

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<PLC01>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_DIRECCION> 0 </ TAG_DIRECCION>
    <TAG_TIPO> MW </ TAG_TIPO>
    <TAG_VALOR> 0 </ TAG_VALOR>
  </ TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_DIRECCION> 1 </ TAG_DIRECCION>
    <TAG_TIPO> MW </ TAG_TIPO>
    <TAG_VALOR> 0 </ TAG_VALOR>
  </ TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_DIRECCION> 2 </ TAG_DIRECCION>
    <TAG_TIPO> MW </ TAG_TIPO>
    <TAG_VALOR> 0 </ TAG_VALOR>
  </ TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_DIRECCION> 3 </ TAG_DIRECCION>
    <TAG_TIPO> MW </ TAG_TIPO>
    <TAG_VALOR> 0 </ TAG_VALOR>
  </ TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_DIRECCION> 4 </ TAG_DIRECCION>
    <TAG_TIPO> MW </ TAG_TIPO>
    <TAG_VALOR> 0 </ TAG_VALOR>
  </ TAG>
```

In the PHP file I'm currently reading and writing in the XML file with PHP, but want to embed a script in AJAX or JQuery that when you press a button, I want to write a value in the "" (in the position you want , TAG_VALOR [0], TAG_VALOR [1] ...)

Right now, I have this, but it does not work:

```
<Script type = "text / javascript">
$ ("# Test"). Click (function () {
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc ("datos.xml");
x = Xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName ("TAG")[2].childNodes[2].nodeValue = "666";
});

</ Script>
```

And the button:

```
<Input class = "btn btn btn-lg-primary" type = "button" id = "test" name = "test" value = "button AJAXXXXXXXX">
```

The file is index.php

Please help, I have tried many things but not working.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you see the console logs? what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () {
    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc ("datos.xml");
    x = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TAG")[2].childNodes[2].nodeValue = "666";
    });
});
</script>
```

Try this. Your jQuery code should wrapped in $(function () {}) means that your code should be ready when document loaded.  And you have a few typos, your button id and jQuery selector weren't matching etc.